# Copying a continuously growing file from one server to another in ubuntu bash

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu

I have some csv files which are continuously updated with new entries.

I want to write a script to copy those files to another server which is going to copy continuously without any repeating.

How can I manage to do that with a bash, or python script?

Thanks,

Comment: How often do you need to update the csv file? What is an acceptable timeline? Would an off the shelf solution like dropbox serve your needs? It seems as if we are intentionally avoiding a database? Could google docs spreadsheets solve this issue?

Comment: It doesn't matter. It can be 1 day, or 12 hours. I want to copy from one ubuntu machine to another ubuntu machine.

Comment: If that is the only requirement I'd recommend checking out dropbox. It will sync any/all files in a particular folder between systems automatically. It's very user friendly, and no programming/coding is required.

Comment: I need to copy to another ubuntu server.

Comment: It seems as if you are against the Dropbox solution? Is there a requirement you aren't relaying to us? Dropbox works on linux: https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx

Comment: so how can I do it with dropbox? which command?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110562/discussion-between-copy-and-paste-and-yusuf).

Comment: Using Dropbox is not only overkill for this problem, it also introduces an unnecessary third party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have ssh connection setup then the following line in a bash script will copy the first file name or directory name (argument) to the remote computer filename or directory name( second argument):

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync -av -e "ssh " $1 user@computer.domain.org:$2
```

Answer (score 3):

The `rsync` command is the right out-of-the-box solution to this problem. From the manpage:

> It is famous for its delta-transfer algorithm, which reduces the amount of data sent over the network by sending only the differences between the source files and the existing files in the destination. Rsync is widely used for backups and mirroring and as an improved copy command for everyday use.

A simple loop of `rsync` and `sleep` will do for you.

Comment: Could you give me some bash example? Thanks

Comment: An example is here https://serverfault.com/a/98750/369380 . `rsync` is powerful in this case. It breaks up the file on client side into blocks and calculates a checksum for each block. So even large and continuously growing files are processed efficiently and correctly.